# Render event from postgres if the date equals today's date or in the future

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to only display events from my database that have dates from today and onward. The date column in my table is 'start_date'. In my events controller I have:

```
if @events.start_date >= Date.today 
  @events = Event.order('start_date ASC')
end
```

I keep getting the error "undefined method `start_date' for nil:NilClass" in the line with the 'if' statement. 
I'm sure as I play trial and error I'm creating syntax/grammar issues as well. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It throws a `NoMethodError` because the value of `@events` hasn't been defined or its value is `nil`:

```
defined?(@events)
# nil
@events.start_at
# NoMethodError: undefined method `start_at' for nil:NilClass
nil.start_at
# NoMethodError: undefined method `start_at' for nil:NilClass
```

For that, you can use `where` to *filter* those rows where `start_date` is equal or greater than the current timestamp:

```
@events = Event.where('start_date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP').order(start_date: :asc)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Once I added your suggested code into the controller, I get this error:" ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying >= date
LINE 1: SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (start_date >= CURRENT... "     Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it `start_date` a `date` datatype column? Try with `Event.where('start_date::date >= CURRENT_DATE')`

Comment: You're wecome! It can be `start_date::date >= CURRENT_DATE` or `start_date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. One is casting the column value to date to compare against the current date, and the other one is directly comparing with the current timestamp.